# GET Fetch working but POST Fetch not working - Google APIs in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-api, google-sheets-api, http-status-code-401

I am still not understanding how fetch requests are structured. In my Chrome Extension, I have used an API key from my console to GET some values from a spreadsheet:

```
let fetch_url = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${spreadsheetId}/values/${range}?key=${API_KEY}`;
```

It worked, but when I want to append some values, it doesn't:

```
let fetch_url = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${spreadsheetId}/values/Teachers!A7:D8:append?key=${API_KEY}`;
    
let fetch_options = {
                       "method": "POST",
                       "body": JSON.stringify({
                                 "values": [
                                              ["Door", "$15", "2", "3/15/2016"],
                                              ["Engine", "$100", "1", "3/20/2016"],
                                           ]
                                  })
                    };
```

I get a 401 response, what am I missing?

Comment: Read about [the status code "401 Unauthorized"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401)

Comment: @Rojo "Valid credential types include API keys, OAuth 2.0 client credentials, or service account keys." as per the documentation. I think the way I am inputting isn't being read, but I do not know what is the correct method...

Comment: Read more about [HTTP authentication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication) and [Authorizing Google Sheets Requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing)

Comment: @Rojo apparently an API key isn't enough for this request? Still did not understand why since I have the Sheets as a public document and anyone can edit

Comment: How often are you requesting a new key?

Comment: @Rojo while testing once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the doucmentation [sheet values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values)

You will notice that it states

[image]

This is because this method is preformed on a private user data. This means that you need an authorization header with a valid oauth2 access token with one of those scopes in order to access that method.

Authorize the request and then you will be able to access the data. There is a [javascript guild](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) which might help you understand how to preform the authorization of your application.

Comment: I incorporated an OAuth2 token with the chrome extension and it worked, guess it needed a higher level of permission, thanks